# Change Vol. to vol. or vols. in Biblatex

Tags: biblatex

In Biblatex, how can I change the volume from **Vol. X** to **vol. X** or **vols. X and Y**?

main.tex :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{book}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

ref.bib :

```
@book{book,
title = {A book},
author = {Author},
volume = {7 and 8}
}
```

What I get :

> References
>
> [1] Author. A book. Vol. 7 and 8.

What I would like :

> References
>
> [1] Author. A book. vols. 7 and 8.

Answer (score 3):

Redefining the field format for `volume` and adding range characters can get you there. I'm not sure whether it's wise to add "and" to the list of range characters, but this MWE works well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{volume}{%
  \ifnumerals{#1}%
    {\ifnumeral{#1}%
      {vol\adddot}%
      {vols\adddot}}%
    {}%
  ~#1}%
  
\DeclareRangeChars*{and}

\begin{document}

\nocite{book}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Output:

> [1] Author. *A book*. vols. 7 and 8.